# Bootstrap alert overlapping button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap alert overlapping `Create Repository` button.

I tried to set `display:block` but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/coolwei/8L5wzr79/2/

```
<a href="#">
  <button style="width:250px; display:block" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 float-right">Create Repository</button>
</a>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" style="position: relative; display:block">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>     
  Success!!
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tz13vp0m/

Comment: consider that float element inside <a> make it 0 height. so you can do some different thing:
1. add clearfix class to <a>
2. remove float from button.
3. set fix height to <a>
4. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the alert overlaps the button is because the button is set to float right. The alert which follows the button hence will flow around the button to the other side.

To turn off the float, you can set the `clear` property of the element followed the floated element. In your case, that's the `<alert />`.

So setting `clear: right;` on the alert will fix your problem:

```html
<a href="#">
    <button style="width:250px; display:block" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 float-right">
        Create Repository
    </button>
</a>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" 
    style="position: relative; display:block; clear: right;">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>     
    Success!!
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tk8eqhm2/4/

#### Alternative

You can achieve what you want without using `.float-*`. You just need to have a block element, a `<div />` or a `<p />`, wrap around the anchor tag. And with *Bootstrap*, you can style the anchor tag as an button with `.btn`.

```html
<p class="text-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
        Create Repository
    </a>
</p>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>     
    Success!!
</div>
```

A lot cleaner!

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/z3q0s8uL/4/

Comment: @David Liang, please check your second URL. I think there's a mistake. The code is not using the concept you'd described above.

Comment: @xoned: opps forgot to hit save before coping the link. Sorry